# azure logic app http webhook with OAuth authentication

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

We would like to create a logic app that subscribes to a webhook in Microsoft Graph. To enable this subscription you need to include a bearer token. Something the logic app included HTT webhook does not seem to provide. Is there someone who has got this working somehow? We would like to subscribe to the 'calldetailrecords'

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is that you can use `Subscribe-Header` parameter from Add new parameter in order to send the Bearer Token to your Webhook.

Here is the screenshot for your reference

[image]

So, I'm passing the Token from my `HTTP request` connector and adding the same to my `Subscribe- Header` parameter with Key as "Authentication".

To get the Bearer Token you can follow the steps from [Get access on behalf of a user - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token)

**REFERENCES:**
[How to pass a Bearer Token using Azure Logic Apps](https://medium.com/gamacy/how-to-pass-a-bearer-token-using-azure-logic-apps-b90d597ddce7)